# Невозможно создать представление с привязкой к схеме

Tags: sql-server, view

У меня есть три таблицы. Нужно создать индексированное представление, для чего его нужно пометить `WITH SCHEMABINDING`. Но при выполнении запроса у меня появляется ошибка.

Таблицы:

```
create table auction (
    id uniqueidentifier default newid() primary key,
    city nvarchar(max) not null,
    auctioneer nvarchar(1000) not null
);

create table good (
    id uniqueidentifier default newid() primary key,
    name nvarchar(max) not null,
    init_price decimal not null,
    auction uniqueidentifier not null,
    constraint fk_good_auction foreign key (auction) references auction(id) 
        on update no action 
        on delete no action
);

create table participant (
    id uniqueidentifier default newid() primary key,
    name nvarchar(max) not null,
    auction uniqueidentifier not null,
    constraint fk_participant_auction foreign key (auction) references auction(id) 
        on update no action 
        on delete no action
);
```

Представление, которое я хочу создать.

```
create view superview 
with schemabinding as
select a.city "city", a.auctioneer "auctioneer", g.name "good", g.init_price "init_price", p.name "participant"
from auction a join participant p on a.id = p.auction
               join good g on a.id = g.auction;
```

Ошибка с кодом 4512 при попытке создать представление:

> Невозможно привязать к схеме представление "superview", так как имя
>   "auction" недопустимо для привязки схемы. Имена должны состоять из
>   двух частей, и объект не может ссылаться сам на себя.

Из каких двух частей должны состоять имена? И что за объект, который ссылается сам на себя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Из каких двух частей должны состоять имена?

Согласно документации команды [CREATE VIEW](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql)

> SCHEMABINDING
>   ...
>   При использовании аргумента SCHEMABINDING инструкция
>   select_statement должна включать **двухкомпонентные (schema.object)
>   имена таблиц**, представлений или пользовательских функций, упоминаемых
>   в предложении.
>   ...

т.е. представление с привязкой к схеме должно обращаться к таблицам с указанием их схемы.

Таким образом если таблицы созданы в схеме `dbo`, то представление должно быть определено как

```
create view superview 
with schemabinding as
...
from dbo.auction a join dbo.participant p on a.id = p.auction
                   join dbo.good g on a.id = g.auction;
```

---

Что касается

> и что за объект, который ссылается сам на себя?

имеется ввиду, что представление не должно ссылаться само на себя в своём определении.

Скажем, без `SCHEMABINDING` можно создать такое представление

```
CREATE VIEW V
AS
SELECT 1 AS One;
```

потом изменить его так, что оно будет ссылаться само на себя

```
ALTER VIEW V
AS
SELECT 2 AS Two
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM V);
```

правда использовать его после этого не получится, но тем не менее.

То же самое, но с использованием `SCHEMABINDING`

```
CREATE VIEW V2
AS
SELECT 1 AS One;
GO

ALTER VIEW V2
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT 2 AS Two
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.V2);
GO
```

даст ту же ошибку *Msg 4512*, что и в вопросе

> Msg 4512, Level 16, State 3, Procedure V2, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 45]
>   Cannot schema bind view 'V2' because name 'dbo.V2' is invalid for schema
>   binding. Names must be in two-part format and an object cannot
>   reference itself.

она, по-видимому, универсальна и может возвращаться и для `CREATE VIEW` и для `ALTER VIEW`.